# Creating aar of Android Library containing jar and aar

Tags: android, jar, dependencies, android-library, aar

I have an Android Library **MyLib**,of which I need to create Android Archive (aar). This library is using two more dependcies, once is a **abc.jar** and the other is  **xyz.aar**.

I have the **abc.jar** file in **/libs** folder of the library and for the **xyz.aar** added it as a module dependency.

The gradle file of the library looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile project(':xyz')
}
```

Once I create the aar file for MyLib and trying to use it with a sample project, I am not able to utilize classes from **xyz.aar** where as classes from **abc.jar** are accessible.

That makes me wonder if one aar can contain another aar dependency inside it. Therefore is it possible to  access aar inside anot

Comment: How do you include the MyLib aar into the sample project? As module dependency, file dependency or maven dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [android-fat-aar](https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar) to create aar of Android Library containing another  aar